# Linked Table from SQL Server to Access has trailing spaces

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have linked a table from an SQL Server to Access database but the contents of text-based columns have right trailing spaces. Does anyone know what causes this?

Comment: Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166159/sql-where-clause-matching-values-with-trailing-spaces/4166186#4166186  Also http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187403.aspx  relevance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The columns in the SQL Server table are probably `char` or `nchar` columns.
In contrast to `varchar` and `nvarchar`, their length is fixed.

This means that when you save a five-character string in a `char(50)` column, SQL Server fills the remaining 45 characters with spaces. That's where your trailing spaces come from.

There are two things you can do:

1. Change the column in SQL Server from `char` to `varchar` (or from `nchar` to `nvarchar`).
2. Before you use the values from the column in your code, remove the trailing spaces with `Trim()`.