# Linq to Entity comparing strings ignores white spaces

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

When using LINQ to entity doing string comparisons will ignore white spaces.

In my table, I have an nchar(10) column so any data saved if it is not 10 characters will fill the rest with empty spaces. Below i am comparing the "ncharTextColumn" with the `"Four"` string. And even though the ncharText will equal  `"Four    "` It results in a match and the "result" variable will contain 1 record

```
TestEntities1 entity = new TestEntities1();
var result = entity.Table_1.Where(e => e.ncharText == "Four");
```

Is there an explanation for this and a way to work around it or am I going to have to call ToList on my query before any comparisons like so.

```
var newList = result.ToList().Where(e => e.ncharText == "Four");
```

This code now correctly returns 0 records as it takes into account white spaces. However, calling to list before a comparison can result in loading a large collection into memory which won't end up being used.

Comment: Couldn't you just do `e.ncharText.Trim() == "Four"`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166159/sql-where-clause-matching-values-with-trailing-spaces) answer explains why.

> SQL Server follows the ANSI/ISO SQL-92 specification (Section 8.2, ,
>   General rules #3) on how to compare strings with spaces. The ANSI
>   standard requires padding for the character strings used in
>   comparisons so that their lengths match before comparing them. The
>   padding directly affects the semantics of WHERE and HAVING clause
>   predicates and other Transact-SQL string comparisons. For example,
>   Transact-SQL considers the strings 'abc' and 'abc ' to be equivalent
>   for most comparison operations.
>
> The only exception to this rule is the LIKE predicate. When the right
>   side of a LIKE predicate expression features a value with a trailing
>   space, SQL Server does not pad the two values to the same length
>   before the comparison occurs. Because the purpose of the LIKE
>   predicate, by definition, is to facilitate pattern searches rather
>   than simple string equality tests, this does not violate the section
>   of the ANSI SQL-92 specification mentioned earlier.

Internally LINQ is just making SQL queries against your database.