# SQL Inner Join for fields when one has an extra character on the end

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, ssrs-2008, inner-join

We have 2 tables with identical fields, but 1 table has an additional space at the end of the field due to our inhouse application adding the space.

The fields are character varying, so I cannot specify a length.

In Access, the following worked with the INNER JOIN, but I cannot get it to work in SSRS:  ON table1.field1 + " " = table2.field1

To recap, I need to INNER JOIN 2 fields, but 1 of the fields has an extra space on the right hand/end of the field.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Trailing spaces are ignored in equality comparisons in SQL Server. `ON table1.field1 = table2.field1` ought to work fine. As should your original `table1.field1 + " " = table2.field1` actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of concatenating a space, it seems more solid to trim your results.

```
ON table1.field1 = rtrim(table2.field1)
```

To make sure that there are no spaces preceding or appended you can trim everything:

```
ON ltrim(rtrim(table1.field1)) = ltrim(rtrim(table2.field1))
```

As @MartinSmith notes in the comments, [trailing spaces are ignored](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316626) in [equality comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4166186/2589202).

You can see that at work in [this fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a6c93/3)