# SQl select statement whitespace issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

Values in SQL are USERNAME=ADMIN PASSWORD=ADMIN

```
SELECT * FROM TBL_USER 
WHERE USERNAME='ADMIN' 
AND PASSWORD COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CS_AS=N'ADMIN'
```

The above query works fine.

2) If I add a space in front of the password.

```
SELECT * FROM TBL_USER 
WHERE USERNAME='ADMIN' 
AND PASSWORD COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CS_AS=N'   ADMIN'
```

This is also correct as it returns a message saying incorrect password.

3) If I add a space in to the end of the password:

```
SELECT * FROM TBL_USER 
WHERE USERNAME='ADMIN' 
AND PASSWORD COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CS_AS=N'ADMIN '
```

This query should fail but it doesn't it retrieves data.

Can anyone help me in this.The third condition should fail since the value in table is 'admin' and the value provided is 'admin          ' (with whitespaces at end).

Comment: `N'ADMIN'` ? What DBMS are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Sql. 'N' is used for nvarchar type column.

Comment: "SQL" is not a DBMS product, it's a query language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you

```
SELECT * FROM TBL_USER 
WHERE USERNAME='ADMIN' AND PASSWORD COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CS_AS=N'ADMIN ' And LEN(PASSWORD) = LEN(Replace('admin ', ' ' , '_'))
```

As it will fail if the user uses spaces at the end of the password.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using **=** operator use **LIKE** (without % wildcard)

```
SELECT * FROM TBL_USER WHERE USERNAME='ADMIN' 
AND PASSWORD COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CS_AS LIKE N'ADMIN '
```

And here's why: [SQL WHERE clause matching values with trailing spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166159/sql-where-clause-matching-values-with-trailing-spaces)

Comment: For this specific scenario `like` would work perfectly well. However supposing the stored password was `thisismysupersecurepassword` and someone entered the password value of `%` - this solution is going to fail quite spectacularly.

Comment: @Barry Appreciate for pointing that out. Went through your suggestion again. Thinking that DATALENGTH would also fail If '12345 ' was entered. Seems like there is no perfect solution to handle this scenario except for having 'no-spaces allowed' password policy on GUI side.

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected [behaviour of trailing spaces](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316626)

> SQL Server follows the ANSI/ISO SQL-92 specification (Section 8.2,
>   , General rules #3) on how to compare strings
>   with spaces. The ANSI standard requires padding for the character
>   strings used in comparisons so that their lengths match before
>   comparing them. The padding directly affects the semantics of WHERE
>   and HAVING clause predicates and other Transact-SQL string
>   comparisons. For example, Transact-SQL considers the strings 'abc' and
>   'abc ' to be equivalent for most comparison operations.
>
> The only exception to this rule is the LIKE predicate. When the right
>   side of a LIKE predicate expression features a value with a trailing
>   space, SQL Server does not pad the two values to the same length
>   before the comparison occurs. Because the purpose of the LIKE
>   predicate, by definition, is to facilitate pattern searches rather
>   than simple string equality tests, this does not violate the section
>   of the ANSI SQL-92 specification mentioned earlier.

I suggest you add another condition to your `where` clause:

`And DATALENGTH(Password) = DATALENGTH(N'ADMIN ')`

This will add another check to ensure the input value length is the same as the Database value.

Full example:

```
Declare @tblUser table
(
Username nvarchar(50),
Password nvarchar(50)
)
Insert into @tblUser
Values (N'ADMIN',N'ADMIN')


select *
From @tblUser
Where Username = N'ADMIN'
And Password Collate LATIN1_GENERAL_CS_AS = N'ADMIN'

select *
From @tblUser
Where Username = N'ADMIN'
And Password Collate LATIN1_GENERAL_CS_AS = N' ADMIN'

select *
From @tblUser
Where Username = N'ADMIN'
And Password Collate LATIN1_GENERAL_CS_AS = N'ADMIN '
And DATALENGTH(Password) = DATALENGTH(N'ADMIN ')
```

Comment: Why not use LIKE operator simply. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use trim function

```
SELECT * FROM TBL_USER WHERE USERNAME=trim('ADMIN') AND PASSWORD COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CS_AS=N trim('ADMIN')
```

Comment: Is there is a trimend function? Because I'm allowing user to have whitesapces at front for password.

Comment: If you are allowing whitesapces to user then not issue you can directly check for exact matching

Comment: As mentioned above, the third query sholud fail,since there is no white space at the back of "admin" in sql table. But the third query retrieves it.

Comment: IMO trimming or length checking would not work. What if user purposely had suffixed white space in password during registration? (I know this a boundary condition and most sites don't allow such passwords, still!).

Answer (score 0):

You can do a right trim in your check.

```
SELECT * FROM TBL_USER 
WHERE USERNAME='ADMIN' AND PASSWORD COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CS_AS=RTRIM(N'ADMIN ')
```