# SQL Server : distinct with trailing whitespace

Tags: sql-server

How can I get this example to display ('space') and ('space ')?

```
create table #example
( 
    myString varchar(50)
)

insert into #example values ('space'), ('space ')

select distinct * 
from #example
```

I am aware SQL comparison operators consider these two strings as equivalent, but I do not for this case.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316626

[SQL WHERE clause matching values with trailing spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166159/sql-where-clause-matching-values-with-trailing-spaces)

**Follow-up to answer**:

Note: the `DATALENGTH(...)` function can also produce a join sensitive to trailing whitespace:

```
select *
from table1
left join table2 on table1.id1 = table2.id1 
                 and datalength(table1.id1) = datalength(table2.id1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.myString
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT myString, DATALENGTH(myString) [DataLength]
    FROM #example
    ) A
```

With this data:

```
insert into #example values ('space'),
('space '),
('space2'),
('space2');
```

Results:

```
myString
--------
space
space 
space2
```

Comment: I had hacked something together that added then removed an extra character, but this is more elegant.  Thx.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve that by removing the distinct keyword in  your select stmt ...

select  myString from #example

**OR**

select * from #example

But I suppose there is more to this question than just this ... ?

EDIT:

```
select  myString  
--, rtrim(myString)  as newstring -- uncomment for troubleshooting
from #example
WHERE rtrim(myString)  not like '% %'
```